# How to add build.gradle dependency for both local and instrumented tests in a single line?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle

To add a library as a dependecy for both local and instrumented unit tests I need to add two lines of code to `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
```

Is it possible to do this in a single line?

I'm looking for something like:

```
bothTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let configurations extend from other configurations. The code below creates a new configuration, that `testCompile` and `androidTestCompile` extend from. This way, each dependency of the new configuration will also be a dependency of these configurations.

```
configurations {
    // Create new configuration
    bothTestCompile
    // Let both configurations extend from 'bothTestCompile'
    testCompile.extendsFrom(bothTestCompile)
    androidTestCompile.extendsFrom(bothTestCompile)
}
```

Now you can use the new configuration in your `dependencies` closure just like you did in your example.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.